# How to Apply Formula to every cell in range and print result for each cell in cell zz new line

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to be able to "translate" for lack of a better term; each cell in a sheet range into VBA.

This means I can instantly take an existing workbook and produce VBA to recreate it.

So I put this UDF together. It shows a cell as it would appear in VBA. R1C1 format

```
Function showformula(rng As Range)
    If rng.HasArray = True Then
        showformula = "{" & rng.Formula & "}"
    Else
        showformula = "Sheets(""" & ActiveSheet.Name & """). Range(""" & rng.Address & """)" & ".FormulaR1C1 = " & """" & rng.FormulaR1C1 & """"
    End If
End Function
```

So 1)show a user select box for specifying a range. Then Click Proceed and 2) the above UDF reads for every cell in the specified range and 3) prints each cell's result on a new line in cell ZZ.

1 is easy enough to googlefu

but 2) & 3) I do not know how I would write it

Answer (score 0):

https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/brndla/how_to_apply_formula_to_every_cell_in_range_and/

Solution Occurred here

```
    Sub BuildList()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim rngInput As Range
    Dim rngOutput As Range
    Dim i As Long

    'Ask our user for stuff
    Set rngInput = Application.InputBox("What cells do you want to read?", "Input", , , , , , 8)
    Set rngOutput = Application.InputBox("Where do you want output to go?", "Output", , , , , , 8)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Write the answers
    For Each c In rngInput.Cells
        rngOutput.Cells(1).Offset(i).Value = ShowFormula(c)
        i = i + 1
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

    Function ShowFormula(rng As Range)
        If rng.HasArray = True Then
            ShowFormula = "{" & rng.Formula & "}"
        Else
            ShowFormula = "Sheets(""" & ActiveSheet.Name & """). Range(""" & rng.Address & """)" & ".FormulaR1C1 = " & """" & rng.FormulaR1C1 & """"
        End If
    End Function
```